# delete the last 2 characters from a text file: shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to delete the last 2 characters from a text file in shell script. 
Any idea about how I can do it?

Comment: last 2 chars of the file of each line?

Answer (score 11):

Delete the last two characters on the last line **only** with `sed`:

```
$ sed '$s/..$//' file
```

If you are happy with changes then use `-i` to store them back to the file:

```
$ sed -i '$s/..$//' file
```

If you wanted to delete the last two characters on **every** line it would be:

```
$ sed 's/..$//' file
```

Again use `-i` to store the changes back to the file:

```
$ sed -i 's/..$//' file
```

Comment: This made no change to my json text file, which ends with these characters: ,\n]. I want to delete all three of these chars and then add back the ]. Why won't this solution work for dynamic needs? Can you explain what the "$s/..//" means?