# Remove last few characters from big JSON file

Tags: json, ruby, unix, edit

I have several huge (>2GB) JSON files that end in `,\n]`. Here is my test file example, which is the last 25 characters of a 2 GB JSON file:

**test.json**

```
  ":{"value":false}}}}}},
  ]
```

I need to delete the `,\n` and add back in the `]` from the last three characters of the last line. The entire file is on three lines: both the front and end brackets are on their own line, and all the contents of the JSON array is on the second line.

I can't load the entire stream into memory to do something like:

```
string[0..-2]
```

because the file is way too large. I tried [several approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411894), including Ruby's:

```
chomp!(",\n]")
```

and UNIX's:

```
sed
```

both of which made no change to my JSON file. I viewed the last 25 characters by doing:

```
tail -c 25 filename.json
```

and also did:

```
ls -l
```

to verify that the byte size of the new and the old file versions were the same.

Can anyone help me understand why none of these approaches is working?

Comment: The JSON file should not have encoding like that in it in the first place unless it's been converted to a string at some point. How was the JSON file generated? What happens when you do JSON.parse on the file?

Comment: Agreed, it's invalid json, you're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: The test.json is just the last 25 characters of a 2GB valid json file. The json contents are valid json, EXCEPT that the last element in the json array has a comma after it, preceding the final end bracket, ]. I couldn't post the 2 GB json file, because its contents are proprietary-ish, but wanted to show what the base problem is - i.e., how to modify just the last 3 characters when the file is extremely large, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to read in the whole file if you're looking to make a surgical operation like this. Instead you can just overwrite the last few bytes in the file:

```
file = 'huge.json'

IO.write(file, "\n]\n", File.stat(file).size - 5)
```

The key here is to write as many bytes out as you back-track from the end, otherwise you'll need to trim the file length, though you can do that as well if necessary with [`truncate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-truncate).

Comment: File.truncate worked really well, and then I did echo -n "]" to add back the end bracket. Thanks so much for your help, @tadman!